# MLR mod not found

Tags: modulo, mlr

I love MLR! In the code below I am comparing the performance of four classifiers. I am getting some weird errors when I run the following code using the PIMA Indian Diabetes data:

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)
data2<-data
## Define the task
Class.task = makeClassifTask(id = "USUBJID", data = data2, target = "Class", positive ="B")

Class.task = makeClassifTask( data = PimaIndiansDiabetes, target = "diabetes", positive ="pos")


fv = generateFilterValuesData(Class.task, method = "mrmr")

plotFilterValues(fv)

filtered.task = filterFeatures(Class.task, fval = fv, threshold = -.2)

#filtered.task = Class.task

n = getTaskSize(filtered.task)
train.set = sample(n, size = round(2/3 * n))
test.set = setdiff(seq_len(n), train.set)

lrn1 = makeLearner("classif.lda", predict.type = "prob")
mod1 = train(lrn1, filtered.task, subset = train.set)
pred1 = predict(mod1, task = filtered.task, subset = test.set)


lrn2 = makeLearner("classif.ksvm", predict.type = "prob")
mod2 = train(lrn2, filtered.task, subset = train.set)
pred2 = predict(mod2, task = filtered.task, subset = test.set)

lrn3 = makeLearner("classif.randomForest", predict.type = "prob")
mod3 = train(lrn3, Class.task, subset = train.set)
pred3 = predict(mod3, task = Class.task, subset = test.set)

lrn5 = makeLearner("classif.xgboost", predict.type = "prob")
mod5 = train(lrn5, Class.task, subset = train.set)
pred5 = predict(mod5, task = Class.task, subset = test.set)

### Tune wrapper for ksvm
rdesc.inner = makeResampleDesc("Holdout")
ms = list(auc, mmce)
ps = makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("C", 2^(-1:1))
)
ctrl = makeTuneControlGrid()
lrn2 = makeTuneWrapper(lrn2, rdesc.inner,ms, ps,  ctrl, show.info = FALSE)

lrns = list(lrn1, lrn2,lrn3,lrn5)
rdesc.outer = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 5)

bmr = benchmark(lrns, tasks = filtered.task, resampling = rdesc.outer, measures = ms, show.info = FALSE)
bmr
```

The errors I am obtaining are:

```
 Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
    unique() applies only to vectors
    > pred1 = predict(mod1, task = filtered.task, subset = test.set)
    Error in predict(mod1, task = filtered.task, subset = test.set) : 
    object 'mod1' not found
    > lrn2 = makeLearner("classif.ksvm", predict.type = "prob")
    > mod2 = train(lrn2, filtered.task, subset = train.set)
    Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
    unique() applies only to vectors
    > pred2 = predict(mod2, task = filtered.task, subset = test.set)
    Error in predict(mod2, task = filtered.task, subset = test.set) : 
    object 'mod2' not found 
    > lrn3 = makeLearner("classif.randomForest", predict.type = "prob")
    > mod3 = train(lrn3, Class.task, subset = train.set)
    Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
    unique() applies only to vectors
    > pred3 = predict(mod3, task = Class.task, subset = test.set)
    Error in predict(mod3, task = Class.task, subset = test.set) : 
    object 'mod3' not found
    > 
    > lrn5 = makeLearner("classif.xgboost", predict.type = "prob")
    > mod5 = train(lrn5, Class.task, subset = train.set)
    Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
    unique() applies only to vectors
    > pred5 = predict(mod5, task = Class.task, subset = test.set)
    Error in predict(mod5, task = Class.task, subset = test.set) :
```

I do get the performance results.. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thank you!!!

Comment: You need `PimaIndiansDiabetes` instead of `data`. `data` is an environment.

Comment: Even when I make the change data2<-PimaIndiansDiabetes, I get the same errors.. Thank you for responding, though..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're loading `mlr` before `caret` -- both have `train` functions and one shadows the other depending on which you load first. You need to load the `mlr` package last (and you shouldn't need `caret` at all here).

Edit: Complete working code

```
library(mlbench)
library(mlr)

data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

Class.task = makeClassifTask( data = PimaIndiansDiabetes, target = "diabetes", positive ="pos")


fv = generateFilterValuesData(Class.task, method = "mrmr")

plotFilterValues(fv)

filtered.task = filterFeatures(Class.task, fval = fv, threshold = -.2)

#filtered.task = Class.task

n = getTaskSize(filtered.task)
train.set = sample(n, size = round(2/3 * n))
test.set = setdiff(seq_len(n), train.set)

lrn1 = makeLearner("classif.lda", predict.type = "prob")
mod1 = train(lrn1, filtered.task, subset = train.set)
pred1 = predict(mod1, task = filtered.task, subset = test.set)


lrn2 = makeLearner("classif.ksvm", predict.type = "prob")
mod2 = train(lrn2, filtered.task, subset = train.set)
pred2 = predict(mod2, task = filtered.task, subset = test.set)

lrn3 = makeLearner("classif.randomForest", predict.type = "prob")
mod3 = train(lrn3, Class.task, subset = train.set)
pred3 = predict(mod3, task = Class.task, subset = test.set)

lrn5 = makeLearner("classif.xgboost", predict.type = "prob")
mod5 = train(lrn5, Class.task, subset = train.set)
pred5 = predict(mod5, task = Class.task, subset = test.set)

### Tune wrapper for ksvm
rdesc.inner = makeResampleDesc("Holdout")
ms = list(auc, mmce)
ps = makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("C", 2^(-1:1))
)
ctrl = makeTuneControlGrid()
lrn2 = makeTuneWrapper(lrn2, rdesc.inner,ms, ps,  ctrl, show.info = FALSE)

lrns = list(lrn1, lrn2,lrn3,lrn5)
rdesc.outer = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 5)

bmr = benchmark(lrns, tasks = filtered.task, resampling = rdesc.outer, measures = ms, show.info = FALSE)
bmr
```

Comment: Hi Lars! I still get the same errors.. Thank you for replying!